# Fill in the blanks with Simple Past or Present Perfect Tense

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

> It is Teachers' Day today, and so far, Sarah (receive) _____ three
> presents. Her class (give) _____ her a plant and two of her students
> (give) _____ her individual gifts.

I am sure that the first blank should be in the Present Perfect Tense. However, I am not sure about the last two blanks.

Shall we use the Present Perfect Tense for them too or the Simple Past Tense?

Or are both tenses possible?

Comment: Because of ***so far***, you actually *need* to use Present Perfect ***has received*** for the first gap. It would be syntaxtcically valid to use ***has given*** and ***have given*** for the other two, but native Anglophones  (unlike far too many learners! :) don't generally like repeating Perfect forms any more than they have to, so those would normally be just Simple Past ***gave***.

Comment: Check out [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it)

Comment: @FumbleFingers makes good points, but Teachers' Day isn't over yet, so a school test might expect the present perfect.

Comment: Isn't Past Simple also possible for the first gap? It can be used for repeated actions: "I rang the bell six times"

Comment: @Kjaamond I think that's what FF wrote.

Comment: No, that's not. Read carefully

Comment: @Kjaamond is there a difference between Past Simple and Simple Past?

Comment: No, but read carefully. FF said it should be Present Perfect for the first gap and I asked whether Past Simple is also possible

Comment: @Kjaamond, FF wrote "those would normally be just Simple Past ***gave***". It's covered.

Comment: It's for the second and third gap not for the first

Comment: For the first gap too, the day is not over. So what FF wrote is correct – **so far**...

Comment: Isn't Past Simple also possible for the first gap? It can be used for repeated actions: "I rang the bell six times" and I think that you can add "today" and it still works even if the day is not over

Comment: @Kjaamond No, simple past is only used for finished things. "So far" necessarily makes "received" not finished, so present perfect is the only choice. "I rang the bell six times today" means you are for sure not ringing any more bells, like your work day as a door-to-door salesperson is over.

Comment: And since this conversation is about FF's answer, which is now posted as an answer below, please continue discussion about it there, if you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FumbleFingers's comment/answer:

> Because of ***so far***, you actually *need* to use Present Perfect ***has received*** for the first gap.
>
> It would be syntactically valid to use ***has given*** and ***have given*** for the other two, but native Anglophones (unlike far too many learners! :) don't generally like repeating Perfect forms any more than they have to, so those would normally<sup>1</sup> be just Simple Past ***gave***.

---

<sup>1</sup> It's *possible* that a competent writer/speaker might specifically choose to repeat the Perfect form in the second and third positions. The effect of this is to add "immediacy" to the current state of affairs - it's an *ongoing* situation where Sarah may well receive *more* gifts and other forms of recognition. But that's a "literary" device, best avoided in most contexts.

Assuming the test setters aren't totally incompetent, I think they must surely be expecting Present Perfect for the first blank, and Simple Past for the other two. Why would they include scope for candidates to choose the same tense repeatedly? Surely all they'd be testing is whether the candidate successfully recognizes a context where Present Perfect can be used *at all* (so just *one* blank would be enough if the answer was the same in all cases).